# How to set a new date in JSON file

Tags: json, go

I have a working code:

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("D:/Go/Go_project/Go_pro/firstfile.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    data1, err := ioutil.ReadFile("D:/Go/Go_project/Go_pro/secondfile.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }
    var migrations map[string]interface{}
    var migrations1 map[string]interface{}

err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &migrations)
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data1), &migrations1)

if err != nil {
    log.Println("Error:", err)
}

layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05.000Z"

t, err := time.Parse(layout, fmt.Sprint(migrations["date"]))
t1, err := time.Parse(layout, fmt.Sprint(migrations1["date"]))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

firsthour := t.Hour()
secondhour := t1.Hour()

if firsthour == secondhour {
    result := make(map[string][]interface{})

    for k, v := range migrations {
        result[k] = append(result[k], v)
    }

    for k, v := range migrations1 {
        result[k] = append(result[k], v)
    }

    b, err := json.Marshal(result)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    os.Stdout.Write(b)

} else {
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &migrations)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(data1), &migrations1)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    a, err := json.Marshal(migrations)
    a2, err := json.Marshal(migrations1)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    os.Stdout.Write(a)
    os.Stdout.Write(a2)
```

And in the end i get:

```
{"data":["is nice","is a good person"],"date":["2012-04-23T18:24:59.511Z","2012-04-23T18:25:00.511Z"],"name":["Kate","Gleison"]}
```

How do I need to change code, that in the end will get:

```
  {
        "name":["kate","gleison"],
        "date":"2012-04-23T18:00:00.000Z",
        "data":["is nice","is a good person"]
    }
```

Here my 2 json files.

First:

```
{
    "name":"Kate",
    "date":"2012-04-23T18:24:59.511Z",
    "data":"is nice"
}
```

Second:

```
{
    "name":"Gleison",
    "date":"2012-04-23T18:25:00.511Z",
    "data":"is a good person"
}
```

Comment: put the key check for the keys other than `date` like: `if k != 'date' { result[k] = append(result[k], v) }` and add `date` separately (outside of loop)

Comment: @mangusta how can i add date in this case? outside of loop, i need to use: append() and which arguments do i need?

Comment: I think you need to declare a map of string-to-interface (`result := make(map[string]interface{})`) instead of string-to-interface-slice

Comment: @mangusta okay and after this? sorry for my questions!

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just my guess (probably there is a better way of doing it):

Declare `result` as a map of string-to-interface and add `date` key separately (I will leave setting its value up to you. I also skipped `else` part since it seems irrelevant to the question):

```
if firsthour == secondhour { 

     result := make(map[string]interface{})

     result["date"] = "value_of_date"

     for k, v := range migrations {

         if k != "date" {


            if result[k] == nil {
               result[k] = make([]string, 0)
            }

            result[k] = append(result[k].([]string), v.(string))
         }

     }

     for k, v := range migrations1 {

         if k != "date" {


            if result[k] == nil {
               result[k] = make([]string, 0)
            }

            result[k] = append(result[k].([]string), v.(string))
         }

     }


     b, err := json.Marshal(result)
     if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
     }

     fmt.Print(string(b))

} else { ... }
```